# Почему возникает ошибка munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer?

Tags: c, строки, malloc

Я начинающий в Си, не знаю пока многих тонкостей языка.
Уже наверное больше часа не могу никак понять, где я нафейлил, возникает ошибка munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *series_sum(const size_t n) {
  
  if(n == 0) {
    return "0.00"; // Btw 0 is not a natural number :)
  }
  
  float sum = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) { // It's simple but I don't care
    sum = sum + 1.0 / (1.0 + i * 3.0);
  }
  int d = sum > 1 ? (int)ceil(log10(sum)) : 1;
  char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * (d + 4));
  sprintf(s, "%.2f", sum);
  return s;
}
```

Уже кучу раз всё перепроверил, вроде всё логично, проверял алгоритмы, выдаёт правильный результат, но иногда тест просто заваливается без указания причины.

Мне нужно вернуть форматированную строку, число и два знака после запятой.

Comment: `return "0.00"; ... char *s = malloc(...); ... return s;` — это выглядит неправильно. Как работает тест? Высвобождает ли он память, указатель на которую возвращается из функции?

Comment: Вы потом не освобождаете память через `free()`? Да и памяти я бы выделял побольше, откуда это странное `d+4`?

Comment: @wololo память там высвобождается. Тестирует нормально до значений в районе 50-60, выше начинает ломаться. Также ломается там где пытаюсь вернуть литерал.

Comment: @Harry d это количество разрядов целой части, 4 это точка, два знака + символ конца строки.

Comment: Там, где возвращаете  "0.00", это указатель на память, **не** выделенную через `malloc`, ее нельзя освобождать через `free`.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, логику примерно понял, заработало. То есть там, где память очищается, если она получает тупо этот литерал, то вылезает ошибка. Так? Я просто поменял немного, дополнил код сюда, в ответе) Он работает.

Comment: @Harry Правда ещё такой момент - не совсем понял, почему это работает, даже если я выделяю памяти `malloc` меньше, чем `sizeof(char) * (d + 4)`, или я разряды неправильно считаю?

Comment: @Harry это жесть, потому что даже если написать `malloc(1)`, то код всё равно работает.

Comment: `даже если написать malloc(1), то код всё равно работает` В таком случае вы пишите за пределами выделенной памяти. Поведение программы не определено. Нет никаких гарантий, что это будет работать.

Comment: @wololo Понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант работает, без извращений в виде "0.00".

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *series_sum(const size_t n) {
  float sum = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) { // It's simple but I don't care
    sum = sum + 1.0 / (1.0 + i * 3.0);
  }
  char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
  sprintf(s, "%.2Lf", sum);
  return s;
}
```